# Como alinhar itens com HTML e CSS?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, formulário

Novamente estou com dificuldade em alinhar itens.

Gostaria que eles ficassem alinhadas os 3 inputs na mesma linha com margin, porém eles descem.

```css
#contato {
  margin-top: 120px;
}

#contato form {
  width: 100%
}

#contato form input {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  font: 400 18px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  margin: 10px;
}

#contato form textarea {
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
  font: 400 18px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="contato">
    <h2>Fale conosco</h2>
    <div class="trbar"></div>
    <form action="">
      <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome">
      <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
      <input type="text" name="fone" placeholder="Fone">
      <textarea name="mensagem" placeholder="Digite sua mensagem..."></textarea>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Faça assim

```css
#contato {
  margin-top: 120px;
}

#contato form {
  width: 100%
}

#contato form input {
  width: calc(33% - 20px);
  float: left;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  font: 400 18px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  margin: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#contato form textarea {
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
  font: 400 18px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="contato">
    <h2>Fale conosco</h2>
    <div class="trbar"></div>
    <form action="">
      <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome">
      <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
      <input type="text" name="fone" placeholder="Fone">
      <textarea name="mensagem" placeholder="Digite sua mensagem..."></textarea>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

No exemplo acima, adicionei ao valor de `width` o `calc(33% -20px)`. Mas por quê? Porque, como você usou `margin: 10px`, o espaço de 10px para cada lado conta como espaço do `input`, e isso faz ele "empurrar" o elemento para baixo, quando ultrapassa os `100%`. Por isso, ao usar `-20px` eu estou adaptando o valor para caber dentro do `#contato form`.

Além disso, eu coloquei `box-sizing: border-box`, que força o CSS a calcular o tamanho do elemento junto com o `padding` e `border`, evitando assim os antigos cálculos que tínhamos que fazer na mão, para acertar o tamanho do elemento depois de usar esses atributos.

No caso, `box-sizing` só serve para ajustar o valor do `padding` e `border`, então o `margin` ainda precisa ser "calculado".

Answer (score 4):

Repliquei seu exemplo usando [Flexbox](https://tableless.com.br/flexbox-organizando-seu-layout/)

```css
#contato {
  margin-top: 120px;
}

#contato form {
  width: 100%
  display: flex;
}

.input-flex {
    display: flex;
}

.input-flex > input {
    width: 33%;
}

#contato form input {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  font: 400 18px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  margin: 10px;
}

#contato form textarea {
    width: 94%;
    font: 400 18px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="contato">
    <h2>Fale conosco</h2>
    <div class="trbar"></div>
    <form action="">
      <div class="input-flex">
          <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome">
          <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
          <input type="text" name="fone" placeholder="Fone">
      </div>
      <textarea name="mensagem" placeholder="Digite sua mensagem..."></textarea>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: +1. Flexbox é uma boa, só que eu estava sem tempo de fazer um exemplo, kkkkk

Comment: KKK o que tem que consertar é o textarea, pra ficar no tamanho dos inputs, mas tem um calculozinho que vou ver se faço aqui depois kk mas, por mim, eu não colocaria 3 inputs juntos, fica meio embolado.